# Why are URLs not resoliving in jsp view of intellij with struts 2 convention

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, struts2, conventions

I have two "errors" with url references that appear when using struts forms in a new project I'm templating out in IntelliJ Idea.  It's the strangest thing because neither of them are actual errors.  The program builds and deploys as I expect

The first one is this.  Now I'm sure that I could extract a copy of the "Struts-Tags" and put it somewhere but why am I getting this `<statement>` or delimiter error.

[image: struts tags]

The second one is of the same line, it has to do with the zero config project I'm trying to build with convention I think.  This one fails to recognize that I'm mapping to an action via the convention plugin without a config.

[image: convention]

I'm just getting started on a project that I plan to use as a template for a larger project and I like to keep my projects clean of any errors.  If I'm breaking best practices and that's the issue I'd love to hear about it but I was rather fond of building my template framework this way so I'd be disappointed if I was I guess.  I'm new to the convention plugin but it seemed like a pretty clean way to set up a business application, more so than my last xml configured struts2 app on 2.3.

Anyway here are some additional references in case there is an issue elsewhere that I am overlooking.

Struts 2 plugin enabled (have tried all 8 combinations of the 3 struts intellij plugins)

[image: convention]

Empty struts.xml file

[image: convention]

web.xml file (some spring stuff cut off but the removal of all spring dependencies and configs did not affect intellij showing me these errors)

[image: convention]
Maven struts dependencies

[image: convention]
Action class... don't mind Data, it just generates my getters and setters, again @Component definitely isn't the issue as I have already tried removing all my spring stuff

[image: convention]

Package Layout

[image: convention]

[image: convention]

If it helps you can download the project:

https://github.com/DrakeFramework/DrakeNelson

I was hoping to get my jpa and 3 deployments configured but I just can't stand committing a project and saying "OK" to errors, that's how it grows out of control and before you know it the 10,000 warnings are all just ignored.

Comment: The problems were actually unrelated.  The first issue was an issue where I had inadvertently injected a language as the answer I accepted said.  The second one is caused by intellij seeing that the struts engine itself issues a warning when there is no configuration.  This warning is not an error, and when building with the convention plugin unavoidable.  The Log4j file will display warnings when the mappings aren't found and default to the package location but IntelliJ doesn't understand that these are intentional and gives you red text.  Basically poor support for struts convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is not reproducible in your sample project:

[image: first]

It could be that you've [injected](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html) something like SQL into the parameter using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> | Inject language or reference context menu. You can repeat this step, but use the **Un-inject** option.

The second problem is also not reproducible for some reason:

[image: second]

Comment: crud, alright I'll look into it.  I pressed a bunch of  random buttons from the alt+enter trying to fix it I may have messed something up.  the sigh is real thanks I got a direction to go down.  Any idea how to reset inspections to default without messing other settings up?

Comment: You can sort the injections by scope, select all the injections with the IDE scope and [remove them](https://i.imgur.com/5m9S6XB.png).

Comment: yeah I found that one last night still looking for the other one

Comment: The inspection definately worked for the first issue, the second one I think is not an inspection issue though, if I remove the struts tag from the form it displays properly (also the log4j doesnt give me the warning message)  [sortof fix pic](https://i.imgur.com/XSVBWdF.png)

Comment: I can also define the action in struts.xml but of course that's not what I want as my goal is to use the convention plugin [like so](https://i.imgur.com/JCXd8Xr.png)

Comment: anyway i ended up just killing my configuration of the ide and now it's compiling without any of these errors.  Thanks alot crazy